# Content duplication Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I'm create an where the user can see content online or download it.

I have a nested table which is duplication and I cannot see why.

```
  def header
    table header_container_table do
      columns(1..2).align = :center
      columns(0..2).border_width = 2
    end
  end

  def header_container_table
    contenido_header = [[{image: "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.png", scale: 0.6}, header_inner_table_rows]]
  end

  def header_inner_table
     inner_content = [["Line 1"], ["Line 2"], ["Line 3"], ["Line 4"]]
  end

  def header_inner_table_rows
      table header_inner_table do
        rows(0).size = 18
        columns(0).align = :center
        rows(2..3).size = 8
      end
  end
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue. To avoid the duplication of content I have to use another method for the nested table which is `make_table`.

so based on the code above it should be:

```
def header_inner_table_rows
      make_table header_inner_table do
        rows(0).size = 18
        columns(0).align = :center
        rows(2..3).size = 8
      end
  end
```